# Is it the right python package "app"?

Tags: python, package

I am trying to run an python program:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!
```

I found it from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world . It uses package "app". But when I run it, it gives an error:

```
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

I installed package "app" with pip. In the file Init.py in package folder(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/app) is no class "app". In file **init**.py are only 2 functions -  hello() and add(x,y). The **init**.py is following:

```
def hello():
    return 'Hello world!'
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Is it the same package "app" that script I found wants to import? What should I do to get the script running?

Comment: That is a Flask tutorial. Are you trying to create a website with Flask?

Answer (score 0):

```
$> pip install flask
```

**my_main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then

```
$> python my_main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
code of the file below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def hello() -> str:
  return 'Hello world from Flask!'
app.run()
```

to run through the prompt

```
py -3 -m pip hello_flash.py
```

Considering that you have already deployed-Installed flask. 
Else, 
firstly - you would need

```
py -3 -m pip install flask
```